# jQuery : Clear Interval not working after stop button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to stop a loop after bt_stop click. But it is not working fine. clearInterval is not woking after the stop button is clicked.

```
<div id="abc">
     <input id="bt_go" type="button" value="go" />
     <input id="bt_stop" type="button" value="stop" />
     <div id="output"></div>
</div>

<script>
     $('#bt_stop').click(function () {
        Get_close('','user1');//enter code here
     })

     $('#bt_go').click(function () {
        Get_close(''#output'',user1');
     });

     function Get_close(id, output) {
         if (id!= '') {
             id = setInterval(function () {
                  chatMSG(id, outpu);
             }, 1000)
         }
         else {
             clearInterval(id);
             alert('stop');
         }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit missing from this code that would make it work.  There's at least 3 forseeable errors, some are syntax and some are logic so off we go!

1)  $('bt_stop') and $('bt_go') should be $('#bt_stop') and $('#bt_go')

2) chatMSG doesn't even exist in your code so unless you're including it somewhere else that'll be an error. (also outpu should probably be output)

3) When calling Get_close() you shouldn't need to double single quote ''#output'' like that.  You can just do '#output'

---

If you do all these things then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an element using its id you shoud add '#':

```
$('#bt_stop')
```

Here is an example of what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/FpgLh/

Good Luck!